# ¿como acceder a los elementos de un objeto?

Tags: javascript, poo, object

tengo la siguiente variable en mi código y quiero poder acceder al valor que se le ingrese al input para luego poder manipularlo, pero no logro la forma de acceder a él.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var maxLevel = swal({
            text: 'Ingrese un numero',
            content: "input"
        })    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría poner un elemento input en el html, para capturarlo más fácil. ejm:

```
<input type="text"/>
```

Pero en éste caso, pensaría que podrías acceder de la sgte manera:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Lo puedes gardar en una variable si deseas.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos como siempre primero debes acudir a la fuente en este caso a la documentación oficial [SweetAlert Js Input](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      swal("Ingresa algo:", {
          content: "input",
        })
        .then((value) => {
         swal('Ingresaste: '+value);
         
        });  
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Dentro de la documentación posee el respectivo método para acceder al valor del **input** y mas métodos espero te sirva y suerte..!!.